# Android Youtube API Available?

Tags: android, youtube

Is there a youtube API available for android?

If not how would one go about getting video's from youtube other than through the web browser?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/youtube_mobileresources.html). First hit on Google. Perhaps it's useful to you.

Comment: It is usefull..It seems its more for sharing and uploading content. I just want to be able to search through content on youtube

Comment: This particular page does not discuss searching, but if you go through the sections on the left (like the reference guide) you'll find how to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The [YouTube Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api) allows a program to perform many of the operations available on the YouTube website. It is possible to search for videos, retrieve standard feeds, and see related content. A program can also authenticate as a user to upload videos, modify user playlists, and more." ([source](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api))

Comment: So this is how you make a query to youtube to return a search for soccer : https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=soccer   Now how would you go about receiving data from this query? Sort of the same way you would for a news feed? And is there anyway to embed a youtube video player into your application to be used instead of youtubes?

Comment: I guess you'd need to use one of the parsers(like SAX or DOM, etc). But I have another question though - is there a limit for search queries per day/hour to this link above?

Answer (score 8):

At the google IO of this year (2012) they announced the youtube api for Android apps, it isn't available yet, but they say that is going to be available soon, you can see the video here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WFsx-u-q3Y

EDIT: Now It's available: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: is it not available yet?

Comment: @OriolJ can you provide any tutorial link or code for proper youtube integration in android

Comment: Sure! here we have all the official information:https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ with some samples: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications