# how to integrate Youtube in my Android App

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to integrate youtube in our Android App. But I don't know how to do that? I have searched enough on web but failed to get the actual result. I want that user will enter his account details on youtube server then he will get all uploaded videos and also he can upload video from the same.

Please suggest the solution regarding the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api Check this link. Taken from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917420/android-youtube-api-available

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

The use of the library is very easy.

code example:

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytpl://"+YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID), this, OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```